# Handling keyboard shortcuts using openjs

Tags: javascript

I use this code http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/index.php for handling keyboard shortcuts.

```
  shortcut.add("Ctrl+Z",function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var val= $("textarea").val();
    var length = val.split("\n").length;
    alert(length);
  }, 100);
  },{
    'type':'keydown',
    'propagate':true,
    'target':document.getElementById("textarea")
 });
```

I have problem when <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is pressed and there is nothing to undo - the alerts 2 ,not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the structure of your page is (a link would be handy), but I do notice a potential issue. In one place you're requesting for an element with id "textarea":

```
'target':document.getElementById("textarea")
```

But in another place you're querying for all elements of *type* textarea, of which there could be multiple:

```
var val= $("textarea").val();
```

Did you intend to access an element with id "textarea" like this:

```
var val= $("#textarea").val();
```

That could be related to your issue if there are multiple textarea elements on your page.